# Remove unwanted matching text from string and get required value using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have string it contain unwanted html tags and text, so I want to remove unwanted matching text and get my required values:

Code:

```
var mystring = "<!-- html-text: 143 --> value 1  <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 144 --> | <!-- /html-text --><!-- react-text: 145 --> value 3 <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 146 -->, <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 147 --> value 2 <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 148 --> <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 149 -->value 4 <!-- /html-text -->";
mystring = mystring.replace('<!-- html-text: 143 -->','');

console.log('str'+mystring);
```

Required  output:

```
value 1  value 2 value 3 value 4
```

Comment: @Bravo I need all value1,value2, value3,value4 separated by space.... in question I forgot to mentioned value 4

Comment: browser code... using node js for scraping

Comment: @Bravo can I add  , |  in same regex to avoid those things

Comment: @Bravo thank you so much ,, thanks a lot You saved my lot of time... can u please  explain this regex in 1 or 2 line if possible so that next time I can do it without any issue.

Comment: https://blog.bitsrc.io/a-beginners-guide-to-regular-expressions-regex-in-javascript-9c58feb27eb4

Comment: @Bravo Deleting all your previous comments makes it both hard for the OP and anyone else to follow where the conversation is going.

Comment: @code - the conversation was going nowhere ... I asked at least four times if this code was for the browser or node.js and OP answered a question I didn't ask three times, then eventually responded *it's browser code scrapping in nodejs* - I gave up, some people don't want help - and I doubt everyone else wants to read me ask the same question 4 times

Comment: @Bravo yes, it is browser code .

Comment: @Bravo actually that time I didn't understood your question.

Comment: so, how is nodejs involved? you said you are using nodejs for scrapping - therefore the code you posted .`mystring = mystring.replace` etc is running in node or on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with regex:

```js
var mystring = "<!-- html-text: 143 --> value 1  <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 144 --> | <!-- /html-text --><!-- react-text: 145 --> value 3 <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 146 -->, <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 147 --> value 2 <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 148 --> <!-- /html-text --><!-- html-text: 149 -->value 4 <!-- /html-text -->";
mystring = mystring.replace(/<!--.*?-->/g,'');

console.log(mystring);
```

Regex explanation:

1. `<!--...-->` Marks the opening and ending of an HTML comment
2. `.*` Matches any character zero or more times
3. `?` Remove "greedy matching" (match the least possible instead of most)
4. `g` Global, meaning to replace all occurrences instead of just one